# Security risk from using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in forms

Tags: php, security

I'm using `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` to output parts of a HTML form to a user.

I'm worried about the potential for Cross Site Scripting attack, where a link to offsite JavaScript file could be injected into the page. However, I cannot filter "=" in my output, because it is a relevant part of my query string. Might filtering equals signs output be enough to prevent a CSS attack? Or is the simply a bad practice (using user generated GET query strings in a form)?

Here's the potential vulnerability:

```
//Attacker types this into the browser:
vulnerabilesite.com/=query=?querystringhere/?<script type="text/javascript">       
maliciouswebsite.com/js.js</script>
//People viewing the website using that link will now execute the following code:
<script type="text/javascript"> /link-to-malicious-javascript </script>
```

Comment: You've tagged your question `javascript`, but from your `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` it looks much more like a PHP question. I've updated the tags.

Comment: **How** are you using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`? Just as plain text? Or element attribute?

Comment: I'm using it as an `option value="$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];"` attribute in a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) call to escape `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` safely for content and attributes, even if you are using single quotes for your HTML attributes. If using an encoding other than UTF-8, make sure to substitute the correct encoding.

```
echo htmlspecialchars( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
```

This is the same code as is used by `html_escape` function in the CodeIgniter framework.

Alternatively:

```
echo htmlspecialchars( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8' );
```

Comment: It works for outputted HTML, but since it escapes my query string it breaks my application. Is `strip_tags()` alone sufficient?

Comment: `strip_tags()` is not enough, you could still do `" onmouseover="BADJS" "`. It shouldn't break you query string. Can you provide example input that causes problems?

Comment: `function eliminator ($URI) {
/*$URI = htmlspecialchars($URI, ENT_QUOTES);*/
$array = array ("&Sort=Date", "&Sort=Pic", "&Sort=Highest", "&Sort=Lowest");
return str_replace($array, "", $URI);
}` I have the following function, which only works when htmlspecialchars is commented out. Not sure why this is.

Comment: Do the `str_replace` before `htmlspecialchars`. `htmlspecialchars` should be done just before content is output, after other string manipulations. `function eliminator ($URI) { 
 $array = array ("&Sort=Date", "&Sort=Pic", "&Sort=Highest", "&Sort=Lowest");
 $URI = str_replace($array, "", $URI);
 return htmlspecialchars($URI, ENT_QUOTES);
}`.